# How do I guarantee the v-main to appear more than 70% height of viewport in Vuetify?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, user-interface, vuetify.js

I'm pretty new to Vuetify, so please understand. What I've figured out is - `<v-main>` automatically fills(stretches itself to) the whole empty spaces between `<v-app-bar>` and `<v-footer>` in order to take the whole viewport size(height).
What I actually concerned about is when `<v-footer>` gets too big. it will corrode too many viewport heights so that it may occur `<v-main>` to be too small. so I made a logic like below to guarantee my `<v-main>` size to be at least 70% of the height size of the viewport(no matter how/when I resize the browser or which browser, which device I use):

```
<template>
    <v-main v-resize="fn_guarantee_container_min_height">
    ....
</template>

......

    methods: {
        fn_guarantee_container_min_height() {
            // comp_container : select the background image inside of <v-main>.
            // I know it's not that good way but I couldn't help as needed.
            const comp_container = document.querySelector("#main--bg");
            const num_height__container = comp_container.scrollHeight;
            const num_height__container__estimated = window.innerHeight * 0.7;

            if(num_height__container < num_height__container__estimated)
                comp_container.style = `min-height: ${num_height__container__estimated}px`;
            else 
                comp_container.style = undefined;
        },
    },
    
    mounted() {
        this.fn_guarantee_container_min_height();
    },
```

But hey, as you know, v-main stretches itself to fill enough blank spaces to make the whole component fits to the height of the viewport(100vh). so the logic above occurs such a lagging effect(stretching and shrinking itself) which is absolutely not intended. How may I achieve my goal? I need a silver bullet! Thank you.

- I've already tried debouncing and throttling, But as I had expected, It didn't bore any impressive result.

Answer (score 0):

@lee can you just add a class to `v-main` and with css add `min-height: 70vh;`?

ie

```
<v-main class="v-main-container">

.....

<style lang="scss" scoped>

.v-main-container {
  min-height: 70vh;
}

</style>
```

Comment: Thank you sir but unfortunately, it didn't work ;(